# How do you move from one view to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirecttoaction

When the user makes a selection I would like the view to change to the appropriate view.

Currently I can pass the Id from the .js file to the controller but the view does not change. I am using asp.net Core and using MVC.

Here is my View:

```
<form asp-action="UserSelection" asp-controller="User" method="post">

    <div>
        <h3>Current Users</h3>
        <select size="20" asp-for="CurrentUserId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CurrentUserList, "ID", "Name"))" data-url="@Url.Action("GetSelectedUser", "Users")"> </select>
    </div>
```

My Javascript File:

```
$('#CurrentUserId').change(function () {

var userId = $('#CurrentUserId').val();

$.post({
    url: 'GetUser',
    data: { userId: userId},
    cache: false
}).done(function (result) {

}).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

});

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetUser(int userId)
    {
        var routeValues = new { userId = userId};
        return RedirectToAction("GetSelectedUser", routeValues);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetSelectedUser(int userId)
    {
        UserViewModel viewModel = new  UserViewModel(_db, userId);
        return View("UserInformation", viewModel);

    }
```

I am expecting to see the UserInformation view, but the view I continue to see the previous view. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm honestly trying not to be offensive when I say this: I started to answer this post but I believe the real problem here is that you are copy and pasting ad hoc code but you do not fully understand the concepts that they are using. Please spend some time reading and understanding the difference between a traditional form submission and ajax, further difference between get and post. The current question will not be resolved as you do not yet understand the difference so nothing anyone tells you is going to make sense or be an easy fix for you. These are concepts are not unique to mvc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That gives me something to lookup and that is helpful.  Only been doing this for three months.  My senior developer isn't very helpful and none of the junior developers are familiar with how to do this either.